# How to save data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In HomeController.php I've got

```
      $ip = Request::ip();
```

Then I would like to receive this IP to my database. But the line below doesn't work. The error says 
   Call to a member function save() on string

```
      $ip->save()
```

How can I store this data?

Comment: Read Laravel documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ip` is a string not object, you need to create your IP model and create new instance using your `$ip` then you can save it to database.

Comment: I did some research and opened a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$ip = new Ip(['ip' => Request::ip()]);
$ip->save()
```

or

```
Ip::create(['ip' => Request::ip()]);
```

should work!

Comment: It will works assuming the IP model exists and the `ip` column is in the fillable.